# Create sales order via code 2017 R2

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create sales orders with data retrieved from my edi system.  I have the code working to retrieve the orders, but I am having trouble creating the SO.  I can create them with an external program using the SOAP interface, but I am trying to use the graph and insert them directly.  I get an exception stating "{"Error: An error occurred during processing of the field CustomerLocationID : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.."}" but I successfully looked up the customer id and location id.  Here is the code for my routine.  I use similar code to create records for a new master/detail set of tables that I created.

Please advise if anyone has insight on creating sales orders in this manner.  The error is thrown at the line: 
    soOrder.CurrentDocument.Insert(order);

I also am getting an error trying to access the extended fields for SOOrder and SOLine.  I currently commented those fields out to see if I could create an order, but I will need to load data in them as well.

```
        foreach (LingoOrderSearch ediOrder in doc850)
        {
            res850 = lingo.Retrieve850(ediOrder.documentId, "850");
            SOOrderEntry soOrder = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
            soOrder.Clear();
            var order = new SOOrder();
            //SOOrderExt orderExt = order.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>();

            order.OrderType = "SO";
            order.Status = "Open";
            if (res850.Data850.partner == "BEDBATH" || res850.Data850.partner == "BEDBATH_CAN")
                customerLookup = "BBB";
            else
                customerLookup = res850.Data850.partner;
            CustomerMaint customerGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerMaint>();
            Customer arCustomer = PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.status, Equal<Required<Customer.status>>,
                And<Customer.acctCD, Equal<Required<Customer.acctCD>>>>>.Select(this, "Active", customerLookup);
            if (arCustomer == null)
                throw new PXException("Unable to find customer " + customerLookup + " (partner:" + res850.Data850.partner + ")");
            order.CustomerID = arCustomer.BAccountID;
            CustomerLocationMaint customerLocationGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerLocationMaint>();
            Location arCustomerLocation = PXSelect<Location, Where<Location.isActive, Equal<Required<Location.isActive>>,
                And<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Location.bAccountID>>,
                And<Location.locationCD, Equal<Required<Location.locationCD>>>>>>
                .Select(this, true, arCustomer.BAccountID, res850.Data850.location);
            if (arCustomerLocation == null)
                throw new PXException("Unable to find customer location" + customerLookup + " / " +
                    res850.Data850.location  + " (partner:" + res850.Data850.partner + ")");
            order.CustomerLocationID = arCustomerLocation.LocationID;
            order.CustomerOrderNbr = res850.Data850.poNumber;
            order.ExtRefNbr = res850.Data850.documentId.ToString();
            //orderExt.UsrEDICustomerVendorId = res850.Data850.vendor;
            //orderExt.UsrEDICustomerId = res850.Data850.partner;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(res850.Data850.poDate, out tempDate))
            {
                tempDate = DateTime.Today;
            }
            order.DocDate = tempDate;                
            DateTime.TryParse(res850.Data850.requestedDeliveryDate, out tempDate);
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(res850.Data850.requestedDeliveryDate, out tempDate))
            {
                tempDate = DateTime.Today;
            }
            order.RequestDate = tempDate;
            soOrder.CurrentDocument.Insert(order);
            soOrder.Persist();
            newOrderId = soOrder.CurrentDocument.Current.OrderNbr;

            itemList = res850.Data850.items;
            foreach (EdiDoc850Lingoitems item in itemList)
            {
                InventoryItemMaint invItemGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
                InventoryItem invItem = PXSelect<InventoryItem, 
                    Where<InventoryItem.itemStatus, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.itemStatus>>,
                    And<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>>>
                    .Select(this, "Active", item.vendorItem);
                if (invItem == null)
                    throw new PXException("Unable to locate item " + item.vendorItem);
                var line = new SOLine();
                //SOLineExt lineExt = line.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();
                line.OrderNbr = newOrderId;
                line.InventoryID = invItem.InventoryID;
                line.Qty = item.qtyOrder;
                line.ShipComplete = "Ship Complete";
                Int32 tempLine = 0;
                if (Int32.TryParse(item.lineNo, out tempLine)) { };
                //lineExt.UsrEDILineNbr = tempLine;
                soOrder.Transactions.Insert(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully, the sample below will help move forward with your task:

```
SOOrderEntry soOrder = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
var order = new SOOrder();
order.OrderType = SOOrderTypeConstants.SalesOrder;
order = soOrder.CurrentDocument.Insert(order);

Customer arCustomer = PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.status, Equal<Required<Customer.status>>,
    And<Customer.acctCD, Equal<Required<Customer.acctCD>>>>>.Select(this, "Active", "ABARTENDE");
if (arCustomer == null)
    throw new PXException("Unable to find customer");
order.CustomerID = arCustomer.BAccountID;
order = soOrder.CurrentDocument.Update(order);

Location arCustomerLocation = PXSelect<Location, Where<Location.isActive, Equal<Required<Location.isActive>>,
    And<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Location.bAccountID>>,
    And<Location.locationCD, Equal<Required<Location.locationCD>>>>>>
    .Select(this, true, arCustomer.BAccountID, "CHICAGO");
if (arCustomerLocation == null)
    throw new PXException("Unable to find customer location");
order.CustomerLocationID = arCustomerLocation.LocationID;
order.CustomerOrderNbr = "res850.Data850.poNumber";
order.ExtRefNbr = "res850.Data850.documentId";
order.RequestDate = DateTime.Today;
soOrder.CurrentDocument.Update(order);

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    InventoryItem invItem = PXSelect<InventoryItem,
        Where<InventoryItem.itemStatus, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.itemStatus>>,
        And<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>>>
        .Select(this, "Active", "AALEGO500");
    if (invItem == null)
        throw new PXException("Unable to locate item");
    var line = soOrder.Transactions.Insert();
    line.InventoryID = invItem.InventoryID;
    line.Qty = 1;
    line.ShipComplete = SOShipComplete.ShipComplete;
    soOrder.Transactions.Update(line);
}

soOrder.Actions.PressSave();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Ruslan.   Just for future reference, what makes sales orders different from a custom object I created?  Should I always insert an empty record first and update key values one at a time?  Is this a framework thing or just something related to how sales orders are defined?  I just want to understand this for future customizations.

Comment: Hi Jerry, the rule of thumb is actually to assign values to all key fields before inserting a new record in the cache. The only exception is when you have FieldDefaulting or RowInserting event handlers on DAC (read, field attributes) or BLC level, which will make sure to generate and assign a value to a key field before the record gets inserted into the cache.